# Removing separator between 2 UIPickerView components

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

So i'm trying to do something in my application, but without any success. I have this `UIPickerView` he has 3 components. The first component is numbers from 0-1000, the second is measure and the third should be a word, but it has to be non scrollable. It should look something like this:

[image: uipickerview screen shot]

Does anyone can please tell me how to remove the separator between the 2nd and 3rd components, and how to add a text like this that doesn't move when touched?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't need a code, I just need someone to tell me if there is a command to remove the separator between the two components. I can't find it anywhere on the web. :( I didn't asked for any piece of code. But thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: You could subclass the picker and try to loop through it's subviews to see if you could replace the one that's drawing that separator.  It's messy, but it certainly would be better than overlaying a view.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  The control only has one state, and that's that skeuomorphic drum state that you're trying to get rid of.  It would probably be easier to just write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cheat :)

Make a picker with two rows, not three.

Then add your static text as a `UILabel` above of the picker - it would look like it's part of the picker but wouldn't move.

Comment: Great idea! I did it and it works amazing! thank you very much!